# R: match () only returns first occurrence

Tags: r, matching

I have a dataframe

```
names2 <- c('AdagioBarber','AdagioBarber', 'Beethovan','Beethovan')
Value <- c(33,55,21,54)
song.data <- data.frame(names2,Value)
```

I would like to arrange it according to this character vector

`names <- c('Beethovan','Beethovan','AdagioBarber','AdagioBarber')`

I am using match() to achieve this

```
data.frame(song.data[match((names), (song.data$names2)),])
```

The problem is that match returns only first occurences

```
      names2            Value
3      Beethovan         21
3.1    Beethovan         21
1      AdagioBarber      33
1.1    AdagioBarber      33
```

Comment: There's no way to know from this which order you want the two 'Beethovan' records. What are you really trying to do? So you have a list of unique values that you would like the others to be sorted by? how do you break ties?

Comment: @MrFlick I'm guessing they probably just want to reorder the levels of the `names2` column and then sort the data frame? But I am confused about the comments about `match`, given that it is explicitly documented to only return first matches.

Comment: Maybe `song.data$names2 <- factor(song.data$names2, levels = c('Beethovan', 'AdagioBarber')); song.data[ order(song.data$names2),]` ?

Comment: @joran you're right.`match()` is surely the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: I upvoted zx8754's answer but he is re-editing one column and not the other: try NAMES <- c('Beethovan','AdagioBarber') ; 
song.data[order(factor(song.data$names2, levels = NAMES)),]

Comment: I would like to upvote zx8754 but I can't (don't know why). Thanks! that worked!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `order`, as @zx8754 and @Evan Friedland have pointed out.

```
> name.order <- c('Beethovan','AdagioBarber')           
> song.data$names2 <- factor(song.data$names2, levels= name.order)                                              
> song.data[order(song.data$names2), ]                                                                          
        names2 Value        
3    Beethovan    21        
4    Beethovan    54        
1 AdagioBarber    33        
2 AdagioBarber    55
```

Basically, `factor` turns the strings into integers and creates a lookup table of what integers correspond to what strings. The `levels` argument specifies what you want that lookup table to be. Without that argument, it would just go by order of appearance.

So for example:

```
> as.numeric(factor(letters[1:5]))                                                                              
[1] 1 2 3 4 5               
> as.numeric(factor(letters[1:5], levels=c("d","b","e","a","c")))                                               
[1] 4 2 5 1 3
```

Note: You'll need to be absolutely sure you get all your (correctly spelled) levels in that `name.order` vector, otherwise you'll end up with `NA`'s in the output from `order`.

(I'm not sure why `sort` doesn't have the ability to sort factors, but it is what it is.)